# What is the equivalent term for 'mutiny' in a monarchy?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that would mean to oppose or overthrow the ruler in a monarch (the king or queen) led by another member of the high ranking officials. I considered *rebellion* but this would have a connotation of a faction of rebels. In my case, the word should rather denote a conspiracy, or an internal struggle of power within the governing authorities while being unknown to the rest of the people of the land.

> Maximus led a *mutiny* against the ruler of the Inhumans

Thank you.

Comment: An [insurgency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insurgency) or a [coup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coup_d%27%C3%A9tat), perhaps? I'm not sure they bring in the *conspiracy* factor, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a member of a royal family forcibly takes the throne from the rightful monarch, as though they had the superior right to that throne, then they are said to [*usurp*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&source=hp&q=define+usurp&oq=define+usurp) the throne.

A [usurper](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=usurper) is often assisted by a cadre of supporters

Comment: thank you for the definition, it fits the purpose I'm looking for

Answer (score 2):

*Coup d'etat* or *Putsch* both imply an action of a small group (presumably of the higher ranks) rather than a popular rebellion.  Mutiny is a better word for an insurrection among the lower ranking military against their superiors.

Answer (score 0):

The closest, as mentioned are *coup* and *putsch*. *Mutiny* is for the military and ships. *Insurgency* is larger scale than you want as is *rebellion*.

But if you need that specific of a meaning, you'll likely have to use several words because no single one will suffice.

e.g. "A plot/plan/conspiracy to overthrow the King of X"